# Nested Grid MUI react

Tags: css, reactjs, grid, mui

[image]

I am trying to achieve something shown in the image below

So far i have got

```
<Grid container justify=“space-between”>
    <Grid container item>
        <Grid item>
            A
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
            B
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item>
        C
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

But my results are like this

```
A B
C
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction as to achieve the results below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include container with an item

```
    <Grid container justify='space-between'>
      <Grid item>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item>
              A
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
              B
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
          C
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like this

```
<Grid container justify="space-between">
  <Grid item>
    <Grid container item>
      <Grid item>
        A
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        B
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item>
    C
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Wrap `AB` container with another `item` which is child of parent container.